# python web scraping login with __RequestAccessToken not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, csrf

I'm trying to scrape a site that has CSRF __RequestAccessToken in the login form. I am able to get the token value from the form, put it in the header and post with cookies, but I get a 500 status code. The result.text contains a message:    "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." and "Our site uses features only found in modern browsers.  For the best experience, we recommend upgrading your browser to one of these"

As I said, I am able to get the token value from the form and place it in the header. Also retrieved the cookies and sent them in the post. My login works when I manually provide the credentials using a Chrome browser. 
Don't know what to try next. Can anyone please suggest what's wrong ? Thanks in advance.

This is the header shown in my Chrome browser when I login manually:

```
GET /Security/Register HTTP/1.1
    'Host': 'www.idocmarket.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Accept': 
 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng, 
    */*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Referer': ' https://www.idocmarket.com/',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cookie': ' __utmz=141398122.1569340638.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn= (direct)|utmcmd=(none); ASP.NET_SessionId=aow5a3q4o0kfdhwu554ma2qt; 
    __utmc=141398122; 
 __RequestVerificationToken=XsNRpnUzlge1NCeddExuVaN_uYheGBROrEHHNLgY5oTxc5HZqVZrXKmnn2IgUquL_tM-uWaebglLrfEpdGIutLYAFdK5EzQGOFeyiz3PszQ1; __utma=141398122.1343771318.1569340638.1570400178.1570490801.9; party_search_type=Contains; __utmb=141398122.19.10.1570490801'
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.idocmarket.com/Security/Register'
EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'somepwd'

LOGIN_API_URL = 'https://www.idocmarket.com/Security/Register'

def main():
    # Persistent login session
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login auth token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    cookies = result.cookies
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")
    auth_token = soup.find("input", {'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'}).get('value')

    # Create payload
    payload = {
            "Login_Username": EMAIL,
            "Login_Password": PASSWORD
    }

    headerpayload = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Host': 'www.idocmarket.com',
        'Origin': 'https://www.idocmarket.com/Security/Register',
        'Referer': 'https://www.idocmarket.com/',
        '__RequestVerificationToken': auth_token
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(
        LOGIN_API_URL,
        data=payload,
        headers=headerpayload,
        cookies=cookies
    )

    # Report successful login
    print("Login succeeded: ", result.ok)
    print("Status code:", result.status_code)
    print(result.text)

# Entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect to be transferred to the next page after the login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this site sets the xsrf token both in cookies & in params in the request (as you noticed in the first place). After some testing it seems the cookie itself is sufficient eg dropping the xsrf parameter from the POST request while passing the right cookies seems to work.

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) for quick testing :

```
username=myemail@gmail.com
password=somepwd
curl -s -c cookies.txt 'https://www.idocmarket.com/Security/LogOn'
curl -v -b cookies.txt -L 'https://www.idocmarket.com/Security/LogOn' \
     -d "Login.Username=$username&Login.Password=$password"
```

And using [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.idocmarket.com/Security/LogOn'
EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'somepwd'

s = requests.Session()
s.get(LOGIN_URL)

r = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data = {
    "Login.Username": EMAIL,
    "Login.Password": PASSWORD
})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: perfect. thank you. It was confusing to me that both were set in the first place